# Determining the variance of a linear regression prediction from only mean and standard error

Tags: regression, variance, prediction

I'm not sure there's a mathematically valid way to do what I want to do.

Let's assume a simple bivariate regression

$$y = \alpha + \beta x + \varepsilon$$

I have the following results for this regression:

1. Coefficient estimates, $\hat \alpha$ and $\hat \beta$
2. Standard errors on $\hat\alpha$ and $\hat\beta$
3. Adjusted $R^2$ and AIC for the entire model

And that's it. Importantly, I don't know any of the primary data from which the model is derived, or any other model characteristics besides $R^2$ and AIC.

Now, let's say I observe a new value of $x$, $x_d$. It's simple to predict

$$\mathbb{E}\left(\hat y_d\;|\;x_d\right)=\hat \alpha + \hat\beta x_d $$

but is there any standard way for me to estimate the variance on $\hat y_d$? Most of the answers here require manipulation of the initial **X** vector, which I don't have access to.

Thanks!